# Не работает метод connect в Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пишу тестовый проект на связке React-Redux и почти сразу возникла проблема: не работает метод `connect`:

```js
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Header} from "../components/Header";
import {Clock} from "../components/Clock";

export class FirstPage extends Component{

    render() {
        const {header,style} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="firstPage">
                <Header
                    topic={header.topic}
                    firstName={header.firstName}
                    secondName={header.secondName}
                    variant={header.variant}
                    style={style}/>
                <Clock width={500} height={500}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        header: store.header,
        style: store.style,
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FirstPage)
```

В компоненте App, который используется при рендеринге все подключается нормально и можно спокойно доставать данные из хранилища, а в этом компоненте WebStorm пишет, что метод unused

Answer (score 0):

вам необходимо убрать слово `export` в строке:

```
export class FirstPage extends Component{
```